# Protect internal (SPA) routes from other users in Laravel Sanctum

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

I've configured Laravel Sanctum and everything is working with my SPA, however if a user create a token, they can inspect my website and call my internal SPA routes (which is not intended for their usage), what i have now is:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(callback: function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return new UserResource($request->user());
    });
});
```

How can i prevent all users except my SPA to access this route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of testing, when Sanctum authenticates UI requests, it sets session on the `$request` while when users call there is no session set for them.

I've created a middleware and gave it to my internal routes, here is the code:

```
class InternalApi
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($request->hasSession()) {
            return $next($request);
        } else {
            return response()->json([], 401);
        }
    }
}
```

and my api.php looks like this now:

```
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(callback: function () {
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return new UserResource($request->user());
    })->middleware('internal');
});
```

***Update:*** As described in [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#first-party-ui-initiated-requests), for SPA requests `$request->user()->tokenCan()` will return true no matter what, even if users doesn't have any abilities assigned.